Windows Server 2022 Support for Intel X520-DA2
One of the major hosting companies is offering us to install Intel X520-DA2 dual 10Gb network cards in some of the servers we are about to rent.
A few of them are supposed to run Windows Server 2022, and I would like to confirm if this card is really supported in the most recent server version of Windows.
This document states that there is no more support, starting from Windows Server 2022
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025890/ethernet-products.html
Here the said NIC is mentioned in the list of supported hardware covered by the drivers intended for Windows Server 2022
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/706171/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-windows-server-2022.html
Both sources are official and contradict to each other. So where is the truth?
If anybody had practical experience with this combination, please share.

Check older driver packs. It may be support was dropped at some point - older drivers then should have it. The DA-2 is quite old - I have some of them, nice cards - so it may just hit end of life with older drivers still having it in support for 2022.

Old drivers won’t install on WS2022. If you bypass version check (doable), you hit support roadblock.

I agree, mostly, especially regarding support issues in future. But how to explain the second document where it is stated that WS2022 drivers do cover X520-DA2?

The X550-DA2 was released in 2009. Microsoft will not help you if this device is installed. The service provider must be assuming that responsibility.

They’re NOT compatible and will NOT work. Installing old drivers won’t succeed, but even if you’d manage to find a workaround good luck getting support from Microsoft on ANYTHING. They will find out about incompatible hardware and point you out to fix the issue before you’ll move forward.
TL;DR: It’s a BAD idea. Go supported Mellanox NICs. They’re rock solid, and you get RDMA as a bonus.
Supported Operating Systems for Retail Intel® Ethernet Adapters.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025890/ethernet-products.html
Under section Windows support for Intel® Ethernet 500 Series Network Adapters you can see that X520-DA2 is using IXN windows driver and not compatible for Windows Server 2022.

Could you please elaborate a little bit on what IXN means? I was not able to figure this out myself.

@Mooh My understanding is that IXN is just a name Intel assigned for a particular driver, which supports a particular chipset. E.g. the linked table shows the IXN driver is used for X520, IXT for X540 and IXS for X550 based Ethernet adapters.

@Mooh To add on to Chester, the driver names are I=Intel X=Ten gigabit (could be 40 for 40 gig c for 100 gig) and N is the family derived from the code name, Niantic in this case.
